# Executable Files are now Shared Library Files?

Tags: shared-library

So what I'm trying to do is open up an application I made using Electron-Js on windows 10, Now the file worked fine before on my Linux laptop but then suddenly I can't open shared library files anymore and I honestly have no idea why? It just pops up asking me to choose a program to open it up with and I don't know what to choose for it. It honestly is making me confused about what to do here.

Distro= GalliumOS 3.1

Edit: I can open up the files through terminal but that's about it, what I want is to double click on the file and it opens up that way.

Comment: You may experiencing this: [PIE executables (e.g. /usr/bin/ls) are detected as application/x-sharedlib](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/-/issues/11) - see also [Why does GCC create a shared object instead of an executable binary according to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519521/why-does-gcc-create-a-shared-object-instead-of-an-executable-binary-according-to) for example

Comment: I honestly do not know what I'm supposed to be looking for in the links that were given to me.